# Can't run test via maven with a package-info.java file in the same package as the Test Case Class

Tags: maven

The strangest thing ever occurred today when I was running a simple test class via Maven. From within the Eclipse IDE there is no problem what so ever.

My package has one JUnit Test Case Class and a `package-info.java` documentation class.

I found that the `package-info.java` somehow interferes with the Maven compiler plugin. When removed the test runs fine.

When the `package-info.java` exists in the package Maven writes this in the log:

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid source release: **/*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

How can I make Maven skip the `package-info.java` so that I can keep it in the package folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem a few days back and solved it by entering this in my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <testSource> **/*.java</testSource>
                <testExcludes>
                    <exclude>**/package-info.java</exclude>
                </testExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

*It is the testExcludes element that makes Maven forget the package-info.java class.*